# Multiple ng-repeats on same element

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have more than one ng-repeat on the same element (i.e. not nested)?

Like so:

```
<section ng-repeat="clusterA in foo.barA.clusters" ng-repeat="clusterB in foo.barB.clusters">
```

I want to use an `ng-if` to display clusterA and clusterB in the same row if they have the same name.  Conceptually it would look something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLzcwbjz/).

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: It only displays the `{{clusterA.name}}`, not `{{clusterB.name}}`, but it still displays the static HTML data associated with clusterB.  I haven't implemented the `ng-if` yet... just trying to see if you can have multiple n`ng-repeats` on the same element.

Comment: You can't duplicate attributes, thats frowned upon in XML.

Answer (score 1):

You could `ng-repeat` over clusterA and use $index to check the same record in clusterB.

Something like:

```
<section ng-repeat="clusterA in foo.barA.clusters">
  <span class="col-md-6">clusterA</span>
  <span ng-if="clusterA == foo.barB.clusters[$index]" class="col-md-6">foo.barB.clusters[$index]</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion.  Unfortunately that won't work since `clusters` is an object.  I'll change it to an array to see if it works though.

Comment: Yes I think it would need to be an array .. any luck ?